# How to install rgdal and rgeos package in R on university high performance computing system?

Tags: r, linux, package

I have been installing R packages from tar.gz type files on Edinburgh university's compute and data facility which is a high performance computing cluster which is accessed via SSH.  Once logged in, I can install the files as the example below:

```
install.packages("/exports/work/eng_AntonyHydroData/Pkges/DEoptim_2.2-3.tar.gz",rpeo=NULL,target="source")
```

There are approximately 40 packages and 38 of them install no problem, but two fail: RGEOS (rgeos_0.3-14.tar.gz) and RGDAL (rgdal_1.0-7.tar.gz).

The reason for failure is given below:

```
Installing package into '/exports/work/eng_AntonyHydroData/library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
inferring 'repos = NULL' from 'pkgs'
* installing *source* package 'rgdal' ...
** package 'rgdal' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++
configure: rgdal: 1.0-5
checking for /usr/bin/svnversion... yes
configure: svn revision: 559
checking for gdal-config... no
no
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rgdal'
```

Note that RGEOS gives the same reason i.e. gdal-config is missing.

I have looked around the net and have found various answers to this problem that mainly suggests to install libgeos-dev or something similar using the command 'sudo' or 'apt-get' but neither of these commands are recognised by the computing cluster system.

Any help in getting RGEOS and RGDAL to work would be very much appreciated.

Antony

Comment: You need help from your professional admins. They will know what 'install libgeos-dev first' means, and there is no real point in us explaining it to you.  In short, you lack dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I thought as much. Thanks, Antony

Comment: tar xjvf geos-3.5.0.tar.bz2, cd geos-3.5.0, ./configure --help, mkdir /exports/work/...., ./configure --help,./configure --prefix=eng_A... --enable-python,  make,  make check, make install

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by first installing the geos-3.5.0.tar.bz2 package and issuing the following linux commands:

```
tar xjvf geos-3.5.0.tar.bz2
cd geos-3.5.0
./configure --help
mkdir /exports/work/....
./configure --help,
./configure --prefix=eng_A... --enable-python
make
make check
make install
```

and similar for rgdal

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your HPC system is setup but as the previous comment implied, you need "geos" installed/loaded. The system I work on uses the "module" command to load programs, so I use "module available" to find where "geos" is on the system so you can load it.

Here's an example from another system: http://docs.hpc.shef.ac.uk/en/latest/iceberg/software/apps/r.html